# CodeIgniter Join with AND?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this CodeIgniter query, which is working almost as intended..

```
$this->db->select()
  ->from('user_issues')
  ->where(array('user_issues.user_id' => $user_id))
  ->join('issue_properties', 'user_issues.issue_id = issue_properties.issue_id')
  ->join('series_properties', 'issue_properties.series_id = series_properties.series_id')
  ->join('user_issues_count', 'user_issues_count.series_id = series_properties.series_id')
  ->group_by('issue_properties.series_id')
  ->order_by('series_properties.name')
  ->offset($offset)->limit($per_page);
}
```

The query is supposed to return data specific to a users comic collection, the final join is just grabbing the first record it finds that matches, regardless of the `user_id`.

Is it possible to do something like the `AND` join in CodeIgniter or a `WHERE` statement perhaps?

```
join('user_issues_count', 'user_issues_count.series_id = series_properties.series_id' WHERE 'user_issues_count.user_id = $user_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new where condition wherever it is semantically appropriate in the `Active Record Query`.

```
$this->db->select()
->from('user_issues')
->where(array('user_issues.user_id' => $user_id))
->join('issue_properties','user_issues.issue_id = issue_properties.issue_id')
->join('series_properties', 'issue_properties.series_id = series_properties.series_id')
->join('user_issues_count','user_issues_count.series_id = series_properties.series_id')
->where("user_issues_count.user_id = ".$user_id) //new WHERE condition
->group_by('issue_properties.series_id')
->order_by('series_properties.name')
->offset($offset)
->limit($per_page);
```

The idea is to mix and match the `Active Record Functions` and print the SQL to see the effect - and tweak them until you get the `SQL` you require...

Comment: Actually I believe it is irrelevant where you put the `where` statement, you could use the same function call and add the new condition inside `array('user_issues.user_id' => $user_id)` and it will produce the same SQL query

Comment: @koala_dev - have you tried it? AR is just a fluid interface of function to SQL convertions.

Comment: Yeah I just tried it, it gives the same output because AR stores all calls to `where()` and produces a single SQL statement when executing the query, it doesn't add them sequentially. Basically the order of the AR calls doesn't affect the query that is built.